# if else statement crash

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

I am bussy with an webstite and i came to an problem.

The problem is that it runs the if statement everytime the while loop loops,

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM spelen";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$count = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
   echo '<div class="block">
      <section>'.$row['Naam'].'</section>
      '.$row['plaatje'].'
      <section class="prize">' .$row['Prijs']. '</section>
      <section class="prize">' .$row['korteText']. '</section>
   </div>';

if($count = 3){
   echo '<div class="whitespace"></div>';
   $count = 1;
}
$count++;}`
```

I hope someone can tell me if i do something wrong?

Comment: `if($count == 3){`.... `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is an [assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) (puts 3 in the `$count` variable).

`==` is a [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (compares `$count` and 3).

You're just doing the wrong operation... There is no "crash", this code is valid and works exactly as intended. The assignment operation always succeeds, and returns the assigned value, 0 being considered as `false`, and other numeric values as `true`. From the PHP manual :

```
var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) 1);         // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) -2);        // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) "foo");     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) 2.3e5);     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array(12)); // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array());   // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)
```

One could add :

```
var_dump((bool) 0);         // bool(false)
```

A little hint in case you'd like to avoid those mistakes : put the literals first. Instead of writing `$count == 3`, write `3 == $count`. In this case, if you try to assign `3 = $count`, PHP will throw an error.

Comment: The result of an assignment operation is the assigned value. I.e., `$foo = 0` would *always* be `false`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this about PHP! Edited.

Comment: *"except in some rare cases where memory lacks"* - wrong. An assignment operation can never fail, it always succeeds. The allocation of the value to be assigned may fail, but there's basically no way in which an assignment operation can fail once the value is allocated in memory (which happens before the assignment itself).

Comment: Edited, since it's only a complement in my answer. You couldn't assign `$count = 3` is there isn't at least `sizeof(char)` bytes available in memory. Yet, this is **very** unlikely to happen.

Comment: You couldn't *"create" the value `3` in memory* if you didn't have enough memory. That's separate from assigning it. E.g., `foo(3)` may fail for the same reason of memory exhaustion, even though there's no assignment involved. (Let's ignore that literals in the source code won't really exhibit this problem anyway, but use it for the sake of argument.)

Comment: I actually added that precision because I hate saying "always". It could fail, but if it did, you'd probably have much more interesting things to worry about than just your PHP script failing.